# How to get the value of a bit at a certain position from a byte?

Tags: java, byte, bit

If I have a byte, how would the method look to retrieve a bit at a certain position?

Here is what I have know, and I don't think it works.

```
public byte getBit(int position) {
    return (byte) (ID >> (position - 1));
}
```

where `ID` is the name of the byte I am retrieving information from.

Comment: Your nearly there you just need to mask off the bit you have just shifted by ANDing with 0x01

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: Checking if a bit is 0 or 1 in a long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092411/java-checking-if-a-bit-is-0-or-1-in-a-long)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

```
public byte getBit(int position)
{
   return (ID >> position) & 1;
}
```

Right shifting ID by position will make bit #position be in the furthest spot to the right in the number. Combining that with the bitwise AND `&` with 1 will tell you if the bit is set.

```
position = 2
ID = 5 = 0000 0101 (in binary)
ID >> position = 0000 0001

0000 0001 & 0000 0001( 1 in binary ) = 1, because the furthest right bit is set.
```

Comment: Actually, that's bitwise and; logical and is &&.

Comment: I would argue that the parentheses in fact make this code clearer, not everyone has the precedence table memorized.

Answer (score 10):

You want to make a bit mask and do bitwise and.  That will end up looking very close to what you have -- use shift to set the appropriate bit, use `&` to do a bitwise op.

So

```
 return ((byte)ID) & (0x01 << pos) ;
```

where `pos` has to range between 0 and 7.  If you have the least significant bit as "bit 1" then you need your `-1` but I'd recommend against it -- that kind of change of position is always a source of errors for me.

Answer (score 3):

to get the nth bit in integer

```
 return ((num >> (n-1)) & 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java the following works fine:

```
if (value << ~x < 0) {
   // xth bit set
} else {
   // xth bit not set
}
```

`value` and `x` can be `int` or `long` (and don't need to be the same).

**Word of caution for non-Java programmers**: the preceding expression works in Java because in that language the bit shift operators apply only to the 5 (or 6, in case of `long`) lowest bits of the right hand side operand. This implicitly translates the expression to `value << (~x & 31)` (or `value << (~x & 63)` if `value` is `long`).

**Javascript**: it also works in javascript (like java, only the lowest 5 bits of shift count are applied). In javascript any `number` is 32-bit.

Particularly in C, negative shift count invokes undefined behavior, so this test won't necessarily work (though it may, depending on your particular combination of compiler/processor).

Answer (score 0):

To get the bit at any position, simply do the following steps:

1. Create bitMask
2. Do & (AND) bitwise operation

In the number 5, the positions are from right to left (as given by index)
Number (5) = |0|1|0|1|
Positions  = |3|2|1|0|

Now you want to get the bit at position 3rd (index = 2)

```
int bitMask = 1 << position
int newNumber = bitMask & number
```

i.e:

```
int number = 5
int position = 2
int bitMask = 1 << position
// bitMask value becomes here:
// 1 << 2 (0001 << 2) becomes 0100
int newNumber = bitMask & number
// do AND (& bitwise) operation with bitMask and number
0100 & 0101 becomes 0100
newNumber = 4 (0100)
```

you can return true or false like:

```
return ((bitMask & number) != 0)
// means if the new number is non-zero, it means the bit as position is 1 otherwise false.
```