# Way to get the bit in position X of a byte array

Tags: java, arrays, bit

If I create a random `byte[]`, for instance:

```
byte[] b = new byte[16];
new Random().nextBytes(b);
```

That means that I have 16 bytes or 128 bits of data, right?

Is there a way to read the bit in position X so that I can learn if it's 0 or 1?

This question is similar, but not the same as, [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354860/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-bit-at-a-certain-position-from-a-byte) that asks how to get a bit in a byte. But I want a bit in a byte array, `byte[]`.

Comment: That duplicate is for one byte, not for an array of bytes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> That means that I have 16 bytes or 128 bits of data, right?

Right!

You can get a bit in your byte array like this :

```
int readBit(byte[] b, int x) {
   int i = x / 8;
   int j = x % 8;
   return (b[i] >> j) & 1;
}
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In java you can not aaccess bits directly. You need to use bitwise operators.

So you could compare the byte whit a nother byte whose bit value you alleready know.