# Creating a monochrome Bitmap with byte array

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-bitmap, monochrome

i need to create a monochrome bitmap on my Android phone.
I have a 1024 byte array `I/System.out:[0, 127, 62, 28, 28, 8, 0, 112, 14, 9...` .
Each byte is 8 pixels( e.g. 62 -> 00111110, where 1 is a black pixel and 0 is a white pixel)

How can i do it?
Thank you!

Comment: no, in this case 1 pixel = 1 bit

Comment: you have to know width and height of the bitmap and then should be easy

Comment: my image is 128 x 64 pixel

Comment: https://ideone.com/Qz247I

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you're looking for. this code will convert your byte array to bitmap. You have to resize bitmap size to your need.

```
public Bitmap arrayToBitmap(int width, int height, byte[] arr){
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 );

    int i=0,j=0;
    for(int x=0; x<bmp.getWidth(); x++){
        for(int y=0; y<bmp.getHeight(); y++){

            int pixel = getBit(arr[i], j);
            if(pixel == 1){
                bmp.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);
            }else{
                bmp.setPixel(x, y, Color.WHITE);
            }

            if(j==7){
                i++;
                j=0;
            }else{
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

and getBit method thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9354899/4083200):

```
public int getBit(byte b, int position) {
    return (b >> position) & 1;
}
```

Hope works for you and sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score -1):

First of all convert byte array into bitmap

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, bitmapdata.length);
```

Then You can convert the image to monochrome 32bpp using a ColorMatrix.

```
Bitmap bmpMonochrome = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpMonochrome);
ColorMatrix ma = new ColorMatrix();
ma.setSaturation(0);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(ma));
canvas.drawBitmap(bmpSrc, 0, 0, paint);
```

That simplifies the color->monochrome conversion. Now you can just do a getPixels() and read the lowest byte of each 32-bit pixel. If it's <128 it's a 0, otherwise it's a 1.

You can try this to convert each pixel into HSV space and use the value to determine if the Pixel on the target image should be black or white:

```
Bitmap bwBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 );
  float[] hsv = new float[ 3 ];
  for( int col = 0; col < bitmap.getWidth(); col++ ) {
    for( int row = 0; row < bitmap.getHeight(); row++ ) {
      Color.colorToHSV( bitmap.getPixel( col, row ), hsv );
      if( hsv[ 2 ] > 0.5f ) {
        bwBitmap.setPixel( col, row, 0xffffffff );
      } else {
        bwBitmap.setPixel( col, row, 0xff000000 );
      }
    }
  }
  return bwBitmap;
```

Comment: he has byte array as input (in "custom" format) ... how this code would help him?

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` will not work with his custom format ... his format is not supported by decodeByteArray