# Truth Table all possible combinations

Tags: java

I am currently working on an assignment for school but I'm lost when it comes to implementing into code.

The idea of the assignment is to create multiple `True` and `False` tables of (`p`, `q`, `r`, `Proposition`). The values `p`, `q`, `r`, can be hard coded in meaning I can just create an array with the values and I do not have to worry about those. But when it comes to the last array `proposition` I have to create all possible combinations out of an array length 8 and print them out.

The thing is I been searching and I can't find something related to this. I'm not asking to do the assignment for me but I want know if someone can explain to me how is it done. This is so far the code I have made it's not much but you can actually tell I'm stuck, also when I asked they told me it's possible to do it in 8 nested loops so I'm currently working on this feedback is appreciated. Thanks

```
public class truthTables {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean t = true;

    boolean f = false;

    boolean[] p = {f, f, f, f, t, t, t, t};
    boolean[] q = {f, f, t, t, f, f, f, f};
    boolean[] r = {f, t, f, t, f, t, f, t};
    boolean[] proposition = new boolean[8];
    int tableNumber = 1;

    while (tableNumber <= 256) {

      System.out.println("Table " + tableNumber + " ");
      System.out.println("P " + " q " + " r " + " proposition ");
      System.out.println("________________");

      int i = 0;

      while (i <= 7) {
        i = i;

        if (proposition[i] = true) {

          System.out.println(p[i] + "  " + q[i] + "  " + r[i] + " " + proposition[i]);
        }

        if (proposition[i] = false) {
          System.out.println(p[i] + "  " + q[i] + "  " + r[i] + " " + proposition[i]);
        }

        i = i + 1;
      }

      tableNumber = tableNumber + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: "`if( proposition[i] = true){`" should use `== true`, or just `if( proposition[i] ){`. Similarly for `false`.

Comment: Why are you even testing the value of the proposition there? You do the same whether it is true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have to create all possible combinations out of an array length 8

You can create the `tableNumber`-th table by checking its bits:

```
int b = 0;            // "Bit index", the element of proposition you are going to set.
int t = tableNumber;  // Copy of tableNumber that you can update.

while (t != 0) {
  proposition[b] = (t & 1) != 0;  // Is the least significant bit 1?

  b++;       // Increase the bit index.
  t >>>= 1;  // Right-shift by 1, chopping off the least significant bit.
}
```

You can write this as a for loop too:

```
for (int b = 0, t = tableNumber; t != 0; t >>>=1, b++) {
  proposition[b] = (t & 1) != 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I understand what it is that the program is doing Thank you for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first part that you are getting stuck on is the fact that you aren't editing your `proposition` array with anything new. So within your while loop you need to have this

```
for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
    if (((tableNumber >> i) & 1) == 1) {
        proposition[i] = t;
    } else {
        proposition[i] = f;
    }
}
```

which I got from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9354899/8947748). It will give you an array of

```
table 0: f, f, f, f, f, f, f, f
table 1: f, f, f, f, f, f, f, t
table 2: f, f, f, f, f, f, t, f
table 3: f, f, f, f, f, f, t, t
.
.
.
table 255: t, t, t, t, t, t, t, t
```

Then you have to have a table number start at 0, then you can display them as this

```
public class truthTables {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean t = true;
    boolean f = false;

    boolean[] p = {f, f, f, f, t, t, t, t};
    boolean[] q = {f, f, t, t, f, f, f, f};
    boolean[] r = {f, t, f, t, f, t, f, t};
    boolean[] proposition = new boolean[8];
    int tableNumber = 0; // start at 0

    while (tableNumber < 256) {

      System.out.println("Table " + (tableNumber + 1) + " ");
      System.out.println("P " + " q " + " r " + " proposition");
      System.out.println("________________");

     /** add code here **/
      for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if (((tableNumber >> j) & 1) == 1) {
            proposition[j] = t;
        } else {
            proposition[j] = f;
        }
      }
      /** to here **/

      int i = 0;

      while (i <= 7) {
        System.out.println(p[i] + "  " + q[i] + "  " + r[i] + " " + proposition[i]);

        i = i + 1;
      }

      tableNumber = tableNumber + 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically what you are doing is taking the table number, breaking it down into its bit components of 0 - 255 which in bits is 00000000 - 11111111 which is every table combination you are looking for. There are other ways you can code this that will save space, but I tried following your coding style.

**EDIT:** one of which is avoid the for loop all together and calculating the correct value in your while loop.

```
      int i = 0;

      while (i <= 7) {
        boolean propositionBool = ((tableNumber >> i) & 1) == 1;
        System.out.println(p[i] + "  " + q[i] + "  " + r[i] + " " + propositionBool);

        i = i + 1;
      }
```

Comment: This worked! But could you explain this last part you did                                              boolean propositionBool = ((tableNumber >> i) & 1) == 1; What is this doing exactly?

Comment: @manny If you follow the link I added in the post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354860/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-bit-at-a-certain-position-from-a-byte/9354899#9354899), it explains in depth what is going on, but it is essentially checking the the current bit. So if you are on the 6th index of your arrays, the code `((tableNumber >> i) & 1) ` finds the 6th bit of your `tableNumber` then the `== 1` is saying if it's 1 then display true, if it's 0 display false. It is important to note that bits are 0 indexed with bitwise operators, so the 6th bit is the 7th one from the right. 0100 000

Comment: @manny in other words, instead of creating a new array with all the bits of `tableNumber`, I am instead treating the `int tableNumber` like an array.

Comment: Wow,  this is amazing i didn't you could do that. I don't know if you can tell but I'm practically a beginner going for my bachelors in university