# Returning the x'th bit of of n(int, string,...)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java: Checking if a bit is 0 or 1 in a long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092411/java-checking-if-a-bit-is-0-or-1-in-a-long)

I want to return the x'th bit of n. Bit 0 is least significant bit.
i need a method like
public static int getBit(int n, int i)
that get n and return the i'th bit.

Comment: You haven't stated whether getBit should return `0` and`1`, `0` and `1 << n`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean?

```
 public static int getBit(int n, int i) {
     return (n >>> i) & 1
 }
```

or as @harold suggests

```
 n & (1L << x)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return (1L << x) & n;
```

should work just fine.

Comment: Or `1L` if n is a `long`

Comment: You're right, because the datatype wasn't specified. I'll edit that in now.

Comment: That will work even if the type is not `long` ;)

Comment: Exactly right. I had just answered for the general `int` datatype case.