# Java: Check if a particular bit is set in a long

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a long and I want to check if a bit at particular position is set or not.

Suppose the long `A`

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 0010 0100 0100
```

So the bit at 3, 7, 10, 13 positions are set.

Now I have another long `B`

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000
```

and in this long 10 position bit is set. ( It is guaranteed that only one bit will be set in second long )

Now by comparing above two longs `A` and `B` I want to determine if the 10 position bit is set in `A` long or not.

One solution is

1. I first check in `B` long which position bit is set lets say this position is `p`. This involves looping over each bit to check if that bit is set.
2. Now in `A` long I can check if `p` bit is set or not

**My question is there any other solution, because I don't want to loop over each bit and I don't know the position of which bit to check beforehand.**

EDIT:
I had a look at [Java: Checking if a bit is 0 or 1 in a long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092411/java-checking-if-a-bit-is-0-or-1-in-a-long) and in this question `x` is known beforehand but I don't know the position beforehand.

Comment: @Danieboy It is not a duplicate, in that question `x` is known.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a certain bit is set, use the `&` operator with the mask that represents this bit.

For example:

```
    long vectorValue = 985739487549L;
    long bitMask = 32L;

    boolean hasBit = false;
    int vectorMaskedValue = vectorValue & bitMask;
    if (vectorMaskedValue == bitMask)
    {
        hasbit = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the (only) 1 bit of B is also set in A you simply need to bit-wise AND the two :

```
if (A & B != 0) {

}
```

Since `B` has only a single `1` bit, `A & B` will be non-zero if and only if the same bit is `1` in `A`.

Comment: I think you need `!=`, what with the sign bit.

Comment: @chrylis good point