# Find max amount of consecutive one-bits in number (Java)

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, math, bit

This is actually a question I found in [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com). The question says to find the maximum amount of consecutive one-bits in a number.

For example:

> `The number 123 (0111 1011 Base 2) should output "4" (0`**`1111`**`011)`

I would like to find the most efficient and compact algorithm that does this.

This was my best shot at it:

```
int getMaxBits(long number) {
    return number != 0 ? getMaxBits(number & (number >>> 1)) + 1 : 0;
}
```

Which works great for small numbers. But since it can recursively call it self up to 63 times,  I do not think this is the most efficient way to do this.

I am aware that **iterating is obviously more efficient** since Java compilers do not optimize recursions without tail-recursion. I just like that I can write it in one line. Real question is if there is a **more efficient way than counting shifts?**

Comment: don't use recursion and loop through instead?

Comment: If the recursive approach is not elegant enough, change it to an iterative one.

Comment: @KevinL Would still loop 63 times.

Comment: If your long is 64 bits, why is your max number of iterations not 64?

Comment: @KevinL it would loop 64 times, call it self 63

Comment: The idea is to not use recursion - loop through the long and examine each bit with something like `if ((number & (1L << shift)) != 0)`

Comment: You might want to look at this: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304705/finding-consecutive-bit-string-of-1-or-0[/link]

Comment: Shouldn't that be `number >>> 1` ? Otherwise you are sign-extending the leftmost bit. Also, can you explain the reasoning behind *and*ing the right-shifted number with `number` itself?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou That is actually true, didn't try negatives.

Comment: In C you could use `while (number &= number << 1) ++count;`, I think.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I got that snippet from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1092421/3666763)

Comment: FYI: Hacker's Delight, 2nd edition, section 6-3 is about this topic and contains some very interesting algorithms for this and related problems.

Comment: A sufficiently clever compiler could have converted this into the corresponding iterative form, sacrificing accurate stack traces. However, Java compilers are usually not clever at all. You will have to do the [tail call elimination](/questions/1240539/what-is-tail-recursion-elimination) yourself. (And yes, this is morally a tail call, because integer addition is monoidal.)

Comment: Before asking your question, specify what exactly you are looking for. I think you know performance difference between recursion vs iterative. So, if you are for enhanced performance with **iterative** solution, it is already on SO, just try to google. (i.e. [the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304705/finding-consecutive-bit-string-of-1-or-0)). Otherwise, if you are for enhanced performance with **recursion** solution, it has been already answered. Go and investigate.

Comment: @snr I know that recursion is not as efficient as iteration due to tailing, I only use it because with recursion I can write it one line. What I am really asking is if there is a more efficient way than counting shifts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] {123});
    int count = 0;
    int max = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < bitSet.size(); i++) {
        if(bitSet.get(i)) {
            count++;
        } else {
            max = Math.max(max, count);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(max);
```

So I have prepared JMH benchmark:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 10, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 1, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Fork(1)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class MyBenchmark {

    @Param({"0", "1", "255", "4294967295", "-1"})
    public long value;

    @Benchmark
    public int testBitSet() {
        int count = 0;
        int max = 0;
        BitSet bitSet = BitSet.valueOf(new long[]{value});
        for (int i = 0; i < bitSet.size(); i++) {
            if (bitSet.get(i)) {
                count++;
            } else {
                max = Math.max(max, count);
                count = 0;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int testBitWiseOperation() {
        int max = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (value > 0) {
            if ((value & 1) == 1) count++;
            else {
                if (count > max) max = count;
                count = 0;
            }
            if (count > max) max = count;
            value = value >> 1;
        }
        return max;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int testRecursion() {
        return getMaxBits(value);
    }
    public static int getMaxBits(long number) {
        return accGetMaxBits(number, 0);
    }

    private static int accGetMaxBits(long number, int accum) {
        if (number == 0) return accum;
        accum += 1;
        return accGetMaxBits(number & (number >>> 1), accum);
    }
}
```

There are results here:

```
# Run complete. Total time: 00:03:49

Benchmark                            (value)  Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
MyBenchmark.testBitSet                     0  avgt    5   3,570 ? 0,019  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testBitSet                     1  avgt    5  84,515 ? 2,188  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testBitSet                   255  avgt    5  85,238 ? 0,581  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testBitSet            4294967295  avgt    5  80,629 ? 0,816  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testBitSet                    -1  avgt    5  66,905 ? 1,446  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testBitWiseOperation           0  avgt    5   2,200 ? 0,297  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testBitWiseOperation           1  avgt    5   2,164 ? 0,011  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testBitWiseOperation         255  avgt    5   2,166 ? 0,030  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testBitWiseOperation  4294967295  avgt    5   2,172 ? 0,047  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testBitWiseOperation          -1  avgt    5   2,164 ? 0,028  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testRecursion                  0  avgt    5   2,171 ? 0,015  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testRecursion                  1  avgt    5   2,460 ? 0,029  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testRecursion                255  avgt    5   9,546 ? 0,090  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testRecursion         4294967295  avgt    5  31,357 ? 0,389  ns/op
MyBenchmark.testRecursion                 -1  avgt    5  66,708 ? 0,349  ns/op
```

On the face of it my solution is lose, but if you have really big bit-array, size of which more than size of long?

p.s. - any concern on code are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your recursion into [tail-recursion](http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/tail-call-optimization-and-java/240167044) to get enhanced performance. It works thriftier for stack usage. If you are not aware of meaning of tail-recursion just read the prior link.

```
public class ConsecutiveOnes
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        long num = 123;
        System.out.println(num + " has " + getMaxBits(num) + " consecutive 1's");

    }

    public static int GetMaxBits(long number)
    {
        return accGetMaxBits(number, 0);
    }

    private static int accGetMaxBits(long number, int accum)
    {
        if( number == 0 ) return accum;
        accum += 1;
        return accGetMaxBits(number & (number >>> 1), accum);
    }
}
```

Try it for `-1` (long), which is `0xFFFFFFFF` then compare the tail version with your version

```
long num = 0xFFFFFFFF;
System.out.println(num + " has " + accGetMaxBits(num) + " consecutive 1's");
// Out: -1 has 64 consecutive 1's
```

Comment: Not now. There is much performance difference(i.e. -1(long)) btw yours and mine. @nickzoum

Comment: while giving downvote, specify the reason, don't behave like a tomfool, am I looking like a newbie on SO?

Comment: (No down-vote (yet:), but: How does this answer `[is there] a more efficient way than counting shifts?`)

Comment: the editing of the question was made by me yesterday. Track days of the question

Comment: (The addition of `Real question is if there is a more efficient way than counting shifts?` was by nick zoum.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an explicit way of doing it i.e. there probably is a more compact/efficient implementation but it may at least be more intuitive to understand.

```
count = 0
max = 0
while n > 0
    if first bit (from the right) is 1
        increment count
    else
        if count > max
            max = count
        reset count back to 0
    set n equal to itself right-shifted over 1
return max
```

in java:

```java
static int countBits(int n) {
    int max = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while(n > 0){
        if((n & 1) == 1) count++;
        else {
            if (count > max) max = count;
            count = 0;
        }
        if (count > max) max = count;
        n = n >> 1;
    }
    return max;
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    int n = 0b1110001101111;
    System.out.println(countBits(n));
}
```

Output:

`4`

Comment: (How does this answer `[is there] a more efficient way than counting shifts?` (approach in the question: # in the longest run, _not_ ld(n)(_position of most significant bit_) like this answer))

Comment: My basic assumption, going with some of the suggestions in the comments, was, in general, an iterative solution is more efficient than a recursive one since in recursion you have to remember the previous function inputs etc. whereas this isn't the case with iteration. So my answer, since it is iterative, in comparison to the OP's, which is recursive,  is presumably "more efficient"

Answer (score 0):

As described by Shawn Chin in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304705/finding-consecutive-bit-string-of-1-or-0/12617595#12617595), here's a port of this to Java:

```
  public static void count_consecutive_ones(int in) {
      int count = 0;
      while (in>0) {
          in = (in & (in << 1));
          count++;
      }
      System.out.println(count);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      count_consecutive_ones(15);
  }
```

Comment: Does this compile in Java?

Comment: You should just comment it (link)/ mark as duplicate then

Comment: @Bathsheba will not because of the `while(in)`

Comment: @Bathsheba no, because it is converting Boolean to long

Comment: For the reason that i've given

Comment: @Treycos I would not consider this a duplicate since the other question was for C, this is for Java

Comment: Also this would not really work for negatives, would it?

Comment: @nickzoum Thanks for noticing, it doesnt.. will change it

Comment: @KevinL it does count consecutive bits of one, not just set bit

Comment: @KevinL input should be an integer

Comment: @KevinL answer is 4

Comment: This will pretty much have the same efficiency as my method. So is bit shifting 1 - 64 times the best way to do this?

Comment: it doesnt have the overhead of recursive call stack

Comment: @KevinL hence the pretty much

Comment: Shouldn't it say `while (in != 0)` so that it works for negative numbers?